# How do I find the root path of a website from a dll?

Tags: c#, web-applications, dll, path

I have a C# website. It references several compiled dlls.
My dlls need to access folders on the website. 
How do I find the root path of the website from the dlls?

I've tried

System.Environment.CurrentDirectory - > "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE"

Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location - > C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files......

I was going to use

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()

but System.Web.HttpContext.Current is null.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the [`HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainapppath.aspx) property, which can be used anywhere in an ASP.Net AppDomain.